# How to specify a fixed height for all rows in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have something like this:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{| c | C{3cm} | C{4cm} |}
Short Text & Short Text & Short Text \\ \hline
Short Text & Short Text & Loooooooooooooooooooooong Text \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

which would make the second row have a wider height. Then how do I specify a fixed height for all rows in my table?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to have the same height in each row, try one of these two methods:

1. Using a `\vbox` for every cell:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{array}  

   \begin{document} 

   \newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
    >{\vbox to 5ex\bgroup\vfill\centering}%
    p{#1}%
    <{\egroup}}  

   \begin{tabular}{|c | C{3cm} | C{5cm} |} 
    \hline 
    Short Text & Short Text & Short Text \tabularnewline \hline
   Short Text  & Short Text & Loooooooooo  oooooooooooong Text \tabularnewline \hline  
   Short Text  & Short Text & Loooooooooooooooooooooong Text \tabularnewline \hline 
   \end{tabular}    
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Interesting links about tables: [TableTricks.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716000233/http://nepsweb.co.uk/docs/tableTricks.pdf), and [Tables on Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)
2. A new approach that is perhaps more easy to modify is:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{array}  

   \begin{document} 
   \def\mystrut(#1,#2){\vrule height #1 depth #2 width 0pt}

   \newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
      >{\mystrut(3ex,2ex)\centering}%
      p{#1}%
      <{}}  

   \begin{tabular}{|c | C{3cm} | C{4cm} |} 
   \hline 
   Short Text & Short Text & Short Text \tabularnewline \hline
   Short Text  & Short Text & Loooooooooooooooooong Text \tabularnewline \hline  
   \end{tabular}    
   \end{document}
   ```

   In this solution, it's easier to place the text. You only need to modify `height` and `depth` for the strut.

Comment: @Covi:  now the text are centered in the last columns

Comment: @Covi: you need to adapt the height by hand. I put 5ex but you can change this height. Other ways are to use  `Arraystretch` or `extrarowheight` or `Bigstruts` with the package `bigstrut` but in each case, some specifications are needed to get exactly what you want.

Comment: @Altermundus Thanks for your method! This method only aligns text at horizontally middle of each cell, and sadly I'm very new to LaTeX, I can't do modifications so that it works perfectly.

Comment: @Covi: ok but what you want ? you need to center the text vertically too ?

Comment: @Altermundus Yes! :) Could you point out how to do that?

Comment: @Covi: Ok, I changed my answer

Comment: @Covi: I only add `\vfill` before `\centering` but my answer is tricky. Perhaps there is something better with the use of package.

Comment: This is a good answer to the problem. It might make the required parts more clear to remove the unnecessary pieces (such as the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages and the `\pagestyle`).

Comment: @Covi: I added a new method, perhaps more easy to use. You place the text with the two parameters of `\mystrut`

Comment: @AlainMatthes great answer, there's just one thing in your code i don't understand: \newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 5ex\bgroup\vfill\centering}%
 p{#1}%
 <{\egroup}}  -- is this a global command, will it affect every table in the document, or just a local thing?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Your second solution doesn't work for me. I copied and pasted your second solution and compiled with `latexmk -pdf` and resulted rows have different heights.

Comment: @AlainMatthes What's more, your solution doesn't center multi line text vertically.

Answer (score 10):

This is one of the places where I find ConTeXt's key value interface much more intuitive

```
\setupTABLE[c][2][width=3cm]
\setupTABLE[c][3][width=5cm]

\setupTABLE[each][each][height=3\lineheight,align={middle,middle},frame=on]

\starttext

\startTABLE
  \NC Short text \NC Short text \NC Short Text \NC \NR
  \NC Short text \NC Short text \NC Loooooooooo oooooooong teeeeeeeeeeeeeext \NC \NR
  \NC Short text \NC Short text \NC Loooooooooo oooooooong teeeeeeeeeeeeeext \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

I wish there were a LaTeX package that implemented such an interface for tables.

Comment: I wish it, too.

Comment: My new LaTeX package `tabularray` implements key-value interfaces for tables.

Comment: @L.J.R: Great to know!

Answer (score 7):

I would rather do it slightly different using a `\vphantom`, it requires a little more manual work, but is easier to understand.

The reason why you get different size columns is the column specifier `m` and what it does. This particular specifier is actually a `parbox`. Obviously, since your text is longer than the width of the `parbox` it will overflow or get wrapped to the following line. As TeX's hyphenation patterns do not have a pattern for `ooooooooooooo` it just overflows out of the table, but this is another story.

In order to have all the cells the same hight, I would use a `strut` or TeX's equivalent a `\vphantom` in this case. A phantom command will create an invisible box with width zero but the height of the enclosing text. We do this with the command:

```
\def\Z{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\Huge Something Long}}}
```

This strut like in manual typesetting will make all the rows equal. The final code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\def\Z{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\Huge Something Long}}}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{| c | C{3cm} | C{4cm} |}
\hline
\Z Short Text & Short Text & Short Text \\ \hline
\Z Short Text & Short Text & Loooooooooooooooothetheme Text \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you have long repetitive tables of the same type, it might make it worthline to define a command `addRow` that can automate the addition of the strut.

By changing the parameter in the `vphantom` `parbox` to any of `t,b,c`, you can also get alignments at bottom, center or top.

As a sideline I changed `Looo...` to a word having an ending with a known hyphenation pattern and this time the overflow of text in the right margin also disappeared.

Comment: I'm not sure that `\bigskip`is necessary. A possibility is to replace in your code `\Z` by `\mystrut`from my last solution.

Comment: @Altermundus yes the bigskip is unecessary, I had some other stuff on top and forgot it in. The reason for making a strut with the `\parbox`, was to make it easier for the OP to change layout by using the [c] or [t] etc.