# Table with fixed width and fixed height, depending on row

Tags: tables

## Description of the table

I would like to create a table:

1. that has 4 columns of a fixed given width
2. that has two types of rows:

   - one whose height is fixed to 1cm
   - the other one with a fixed height of 4cm
3. where the text is vertically centered inside the cell
4. where one could `\newline` inside a cell.

(The points 3. and 4. are less important)

Can anyone help me?

## Some things I've tried

I've looked for a solution but didn't find anything. The best I've seen is

- `\usepackage{makecell}` for 4.
- [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12762/8323) for 2 : using `\vbox to 15ex{}` for instance. But the vertical space is added to the content, not integrated.
- For 1. there are on the contrary a lot of posted solutions (`p{cm}`, etc.)).

## Drawing

I've made a drawing that shows what the table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get exact rowheights, that may depend on printer, printerdriver and so on. But you can play with the height of the rule in the first column to make ends meet.

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\Centering}m{4cm}}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.001}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0pt}@{}FFFF}\toprule
\rule{0pt}{1cm} & \textbf{first column} & \textbf{second} & \textbf{third}& \textbf{fourth} \\\midrule{}
  \rule{0pt}{5cm}& some text & some longer text, which will take some lines, if you
                              need, look for the command arraybackslash &
                            The text should be centered vertically as well & last
                                                                             column\\\midrule
  \rule{0pt}{1cm}& next line & & & \\\midrule

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's perfect but if you add vertical rule between the columns (`\begin{tabular}{@{}m{0pt}@{}|F|F|F|F|}`) there are small white spaces (but it is not so important for what I want to do)