# Table too long for one page

Tags: tabularx

I am using tabularx to create a pretty long table, however I do not understand how to spread it over more than just one page. I tried wrapping it in a longtable environment, however this just ends up giving me a bunch of errors. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

```
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\
\toprule
MD - Managing Director \newline H\&SC - Health and Safety Co-coordinator \newline HSA - Health and Safety Administrator\newline PM - Project Manager\newline SPM - Senior Project Managers\newline SE - Senior Engineer/Senior lecturer\newline OM - Operations Manager & MD & H\&SC & HSA & PM & CSM & SPM & SE & OM \\ \midrule
General Health \& Safety  Management                                                                                                                                                                                                                          &    &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Managing Health And Safety At Work                                                                                                                                                                                                                           &    &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Risk Assessment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              &    &       & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark   & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark  \\ \midrule
Safe Systems Of Work                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         &    & \checkmark     & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark   & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark  \\ \midrule
Control Of Contractors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &    & \checkmark     & \checkmark   &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Action On Enforcement Authority Reports                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \checkmark  & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Accident Control}   \\ \midrule
Accident, Incident And Ill Health Reporting                                                                                                                                                                                                                  &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Accident Investigation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
First Aid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Near Miss/Hazard Reporting                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Work Equipment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               &    &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Access Equipment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &    & \checkmark     &     & \checkmark  &     &     & \checkmark  &    \\ \midrule
Display Screen Equipment (DSE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & \checkmark  & \checkmark     & \checkmark   &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Hand Tools                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Office Equipment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             &    & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
Safety Harnesses And Lanyards                                                                                                                                                                                                                                &    & \checkmark     &     & \checkmark  &     &     & \checkmark  &   \\ \midrule
The Provision And Use Of Machinery &  \checkmark &  \checkmark &         &       &       &       &       &      \\ \midrule 
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Personnel}   \\ \midrule
Disability Discrimination Compliance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Health And Safety Information For Employees & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Health And Safety Of Visitors & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Health And Safety Training & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & \\ \midrule
Manual Handling & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
Occupational Health / Health Surveillance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Personal Protective Equipment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Substance And Alcohol Abuse & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Welfare And The Working Environment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Workplace Health And Safety & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Premises}   \\ \midrule
Building Services  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Cleaning  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Control Of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Waste  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Electrical Safety  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Fire Safety - Arrangements And Procedures  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & \\ \midrule
Pest Control  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Premises  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Racking, Sotrage Systems And Mezzanine Floors  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
Slips, Trips And Falls  & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
Staff Amenities And Rest Rooms  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Role and Responsibility Matrix}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...If you are looking for `auto pagebreak` in table, then please refer the documentation of  `longtable.sty`

Comment: You shouldn't use the rules from `booktabs` with vertical rules – they're not designed for that.

Answer (score 2):

Use package `xltabular` instead and *not* the environment `table`. Look for the documentation of package `longtable` for repeating headers/footers.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\
\toprule
        MD - Managing Director \newline H\&SC - Health and Safety Co-coordinator \newline HSA - Health and 
        Safety Administrator\newline PM - Project Manager\newline SPM - Senior Project Managers\newline SE - 
        Senior Engineer/Senior lecturer\newline OM - Operations Manager & MD & H\&SC & HSA & PM & CSM & SPM & 
        SE & OM \\ \midrule
        General Health \& Safety  
        Management                                                                                            

                      &
            &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Managing Health And Safety At 
        Work                                                                                                  

                           &
            &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Risk 
        Assessment                                                                                            

                                                    &
            &       & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark   & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark  \\ 
        \midrule
        Safe Systems Of 
        Work                                                                                                  

                                         &
            & \checkmark     & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & \checkmark   & \checkmark   & \checkmark  & 
        \checkmark  \\ \midrule
        Control Of 
        Contractors                                                                                           

                                              &
            & \checkmark     & \checkmark   &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Action On Enforcement Authority 
        Reports                                                                                               

                         &
         \checkmark  & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Accident Control}   \\ \midrule
        Accident, Incident And Ill Health 
        Reporting                                                                                             

                       &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Accident 
        Investigation                                                                                         

                                                &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        First 
        Aid                                                                                                   

                                                   &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Near Miss/Hazard 
        Reporting                                                                                             

                                        &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Work 
        Equipment                                                                                             

                                                    &
            &       &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Access 
        Equipment                                                                                             

                                                  &
            & \checkmark     &     & \checkmark  &     &     & \checkmark  &    \\ \midrule
        Display Screen Equipment 
        (DSE)                                                                                                 

                                &
         \checkmark  & \checkmark     & \checkmark   &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Hand 
        Tools                                                                                                 

                                                    &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Office 
        Equipment                                                                                             

                                                  &
            & \checkmark     &     &    &     &     &    &    \\ \midrule
        Safety Harnesses And 
        Lanyards                                                                                              

                                    &
            & \checkmark     &     & \checkmark  &     &     & \checkmark  &   \\ \midrule
        The Provision And Use Of Machinery &  \checkmark &  \checkmark &         &       &       &       
        &       &      \\ \midrule 
        \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Personnel}   \\ \midrule
        Disability Discrimination Compliance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Health And Safety Information For Employees & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Health And Safety Of Visitors & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Health And Safety Training & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Manual Handling & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
        Occupational Health / Health Surveillance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Personal Protective Equipment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Substance And Alcohol Abuse & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Welfare And The Working Environment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Workplace Health And Safety & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Premises}   \\ \midrule
        Building Services  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Cleaning  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Control Of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Waste  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Electrical Safety  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Fire Safety - Arrangements And Procedures  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & \\ \midrule
        Pest Control  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Premises  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Racking, Sotrage Systems And Mezzanine Floors  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \midrule
        Slips, Trips And Falls  & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \midrule
        Staff Amenities And Rest Rooms  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this just gives me a lot of errors concerning alignment 
`Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. <template> ... width\arrayrulewidth }\endtemplate 
                                                  
l.106 \end{xltabular}
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ... width\arrayrulewidth }\endtemplate 
                                                  
l.106 \end{xltabular}
Misplaced \noalign.
\toprule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\abovetopsep \global \@b...
l.106 \end{xltabular}`

Comment: then you did something wrong. I edited my answer and copied the complete tabular code.

Comment: @user187802 Do not use booktabs-rules in combination with horizontal rules. Or do not use horzontal rules in the table.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different layout of the table, and the use of either [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) to take care of page breaks. In my opinion, this type of tabulars should be typeset with equal row heights and with equal column width for similar type of columns.

### longtable

I have set up [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) to repeat the header on each new page.

Equal row heights is achieved by defining two commands, `\hz` and `\tz`\, which use and invisible line to fix the height. Vertical and horizontal centring are achieved by using `m{}`-columns, and redirect the `\centering` command into the row using array’s `>{\centering}`. Unfortunately, the `\hz` code did not work when using `\multicolumn`, so I needed a tenth zero width column without any `\tabcolsep`s, see `(@{}m{0pt}@{})`. All column widths are calculated as fraction of the `linewidth`.

> The code for `\hz` and `\tz` is adapted from Yiannis Lazarides code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12780/9632)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[innermargin=2.9cm, outermargin=2.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, longtable, array}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

% Formula updated 2019.08.13 First version was wrong logic (but OK result) 
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr(((\linewidth/11)*3)-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)}}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr((\linewidth/11)-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)}}

\newcommand{\mcix}[1]{\multicolumn{9}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)}|}{#1}}

\def\hz{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\rule{1cm}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}}}}
\def\tz{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\rule{0pt}{3.5\normalbaselineskip}}}}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0pt}@{}|H|*{8}{T|}}
%\caption{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\
\hline
\hz&\mcix{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\ \hline
\hz && MD & H\&SC & HSA & PM & CSM & SPM & SE & OM
\endhead\hline
\hz&\multicolumn{9}{c|}{Role and Responsibility Matrix}\\\hline
\hz&& MD & H\&SC & HSA & PM & CSM & SPM & SE & OM \\ \hline

\tz&\multicolumn{9}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)}|}{\footnotesize \emph{MD} -- Managing Director\quad \emph{H\&SC} -- Health and Safety Co-coordinator\quad \emph{HSA} -- Health and 
Safety Administrator\quad \emph{PM} -- Project Manager\quad \emph{SPM} -- Senior Project Managers\quad \emph{SE} -- 
Senior Engineer/ Senior Lecturer\quad \emph{OM} -- Operations Manager}\endfirsthead\hline
\tz & General Health \& Safety Management &  & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Managing Health and Safety at Work & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Risk Assessment && & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\\hline
\tz & Safe Systems of Work & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &  \checkmark \\ \hline
\tz &Control of Contractors  & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Action on Enforcement Authority  Reports  &  \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\hz& \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Accident Control} \\ \hline
 \tz &Accident, Incident and Ill Health  Reporting  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
 \tz &Accident  Investigation  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & First  Aid  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Near Miss/Hazard  Reporting  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Work  Equipment  & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Access  Equipment  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \hline
\tz & Display Screen Equipment  (DSE)  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Hand Tools  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Office  Equipment  & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Safety Harnesses and Lanyards  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \hline
\tz & The Provision and Use of Machinery & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline 
\hz & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Personnel} \\ \hline
\tz & Disability Discrimination Compliance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Health and Safety Information for Employees & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Health and Safety of Visitors & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Health and Safety Training & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz & Manual Handling & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \\ \hline
\tz& Occupational Health/ Health Surveillance & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Personal Protective Equipment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Substance and Alcohol Abuse & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Welfare and the Working Environment & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Workplace Health and Safety & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \hline
\hz& \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Premises} \\ \hline
\tz& Building Services & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Cleaning & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Control of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Waste & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Electrical Safety & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Fire Safety -- Arrangements and Procedures & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Pest Control & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Premises & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Racking, Storage Systems and Mezzanine Floors & & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
\tz& Slips, Trips and Falls & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \\ \hline
\tz&Staff Amenities and Rest Rooms & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & & & \\ \hline
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

### [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)

The two first rows are repeating headings, inside the `\thead{...}`. The height of the column is set by three defined short-hands (`\hth`, `\htt` and `\httii`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[innermargin=2.9cm, outermargin=2.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, cals}
\usepackage{microtype}


%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hth}{\ht\cals@current@row=1.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand*{\htt}{\ht\cals@current@row=3.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand*{\httii}{\ht\cals@current@row=4.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand*{\cals@AtBeginCell}{\vfil}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{calstable}[l]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr((\columnwidth)/11)*3\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/11\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 12

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt} % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt} % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}

\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0.5em}
\setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0.25em}
\setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0.25em}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}


% R1H1
\thead{%\bfseries%
\brow
    \nc{ltb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Role and Responsibility Matrix}
    \hth
\erow
% R2H2
\brow
    \cell{} 
    \cell{MD}
    \cell{H\&SC}
    \cell{HSA} 
    \cell{PM}
    \cell{CSM} 
    \cell{SPM}
    \cell{SE} 
    \cell{OM}
    \hth
\erow
\mdseries%
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\nointerlineskip
\textit{\strut }\par}
%R3B3
\brow
    \nc{ltb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\emph{MD} -- Managing Director\\
    \emph{H\,\&\,SC} -- Health and Safety Co-coordinator\\
    \emph{HSA} -- Health and Safety Administrator\\
    \emph{PM} -- Project Manager}
    \rb\lb\cell{}\lb\rb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\emph{CSM} -- \\
    \emph{SPM} -- Senior Project Managers\\
    \emph{SE} -- Senior Engineer/ Senior Lecturer\\
    \emph{OM} -- Operations Manager}
    \httii
\erow
%R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{General Health \,\&\\ Safety Management}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Managing Health\\ and Safety at Work}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Risk Assessment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Safe Systems of Work}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Control of Contractors}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Action on Enforcement\\ Authority Reports}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \nc{ltb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Accident Control}
    \hth
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Accident, Incident and\\ Ill Health Reporting}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Accident Investigation}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{First Aid}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Near Miss/\\Hazard Reporting}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Work Equipment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Access Equipment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Display Screen\\ Equipment (DSE)}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Hand Tools}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Office Equipment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Safety Harnesses\\and Lanyards}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{The Provision and\\ Use of Machinery}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \nc{ltb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Personnel}
    \hth
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Disability\,Discrimination Compliance}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Health and Safety\\ Information for\\ Employees}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Health and Safety\\ of Visitors}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Health and Safety\\ Training}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Manual Handling}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Occupational Health/\\Health Surveillance}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Personal Protective\\ Equipment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Substance and\\ Alcohol Abuse}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Welfare and the Working Environment}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Workplace Health\\ and Safety}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \nc{ltb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{tb} 
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Premises}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Building Services}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Cleaning}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Control of Hazardous and Non-Hazardous Waste}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Electrical Safety}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Fire Safety -- Arrange-\\ments and Procedures}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Pest Control}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Premises}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \hth
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Racking,\,Storage\,Systems and Mezzanine Floors}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% RxBy
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Slips, Trips and Falls}
    \alignC\cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
%% R4B1
\brow
    \alignL\cell{Staff Amenities\\ and Rest Rooms}
    \alignC\cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{\checkmark}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \htt
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```