# How to set a fixed height to a colorbox?

Tags: height, colorbox

I currently have a simple colorbox, I would like to increase its height. Is there a way to set a fixed height, or maybe a kind of padding? I added \hspace to add some space horizontally, but a \vspace has no effect.

I have package xcolor imported.

It is currently in a minipage as I want this text to be next to a logo. I am relatively new to LaTeX, there might beginner errors.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper,final]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

...

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{logo}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \raggedleft
        \colorbox{red}{
            \hspace{0.5cm}
            {\color{white}\large My text }
            \hspace{0.5cm}
        }
    \end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the height by inserting a `\vphantom`\ with the value you request for the height. In my example, I set the height to 2.5 cm.

> The code for `\hz` is adapted from Yiannis Lazarides code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12780/9632).

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\hz}{\vphantom{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\rule{1cm}{2.5cm}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{logo}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \colorbox{red}{%
         \hz
         \hspace*{0.5cm}%
        {\color{white}\large My text }%
         \hspace*{0.5cm}%
    }
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use \def, use \newcommand.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I said, I copied the code from another answer, and taken into account who wrote the answer, I assumed `\def` was safe. However, I will change to `\newcommand`.